# maven-deploy-plugin goal failed to achieved - working fine in window agent, build failed in Unix agent (Azure Pipeline)

Tags: maven, azure-pipelines, mule, pom.xml, mulesoft

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project **xxxxxxxxxx**: Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.getBufferCapacityForTransfer(J)I
```

Same pom.xml was used in two agents but error occurs in unix agent. Anyone knows what is the possible reason for the error?

Comment: Version of Maven in both systems? Share the pom also.

Answer (score 1):

The version of Maven on the Unix system is probably old and not compatible with the Mule Maven Plugin. Try upgrading to a newer version that is compatible.

The issue is documented at this KB article: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/An-API-incompatibility-was-encountered-while-executing-org-apache-maven-plugins-maven-deploy-plugin-while-deploying-an-asset-to-Exchange-using-Exchange-Maven-Facade-v3